# How to solve error: Failed to initialize NSS library?

Tags: centos7

error: Failed to initialize NSS library
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Have tried all the solutions so far available on the internet. Nothing works. Please help.